# Java script json parse object : Not removing the "," after the delete operation

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert string to the JS Object. It is successfully using the JSON.parse method, but the problem is, when we delete some thing from the object it is missing/not deleting the ",". Check this program and output:

```
var jsonString =    '[{"connectionName" : "conn1", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.1","port" : "80"}, {"connectionName" : "conn2", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"}]';

var a  = JSON.parse(jsonString); // Successfully converted to Object and i can access them

delete a[1]; //deletes the conn2

var obj = {"connectionName" : "conn3", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"};

a.push(obj); 
console.dir(a);
```

Output:

```
[ { connectionName: 'conn1', ipaddress: '127.0.0.1', port: '80' },
  ,
  { connectionName: 'conn3',
    ipaddress: '127.0.0.100',
    port: '760' } ]
```

Can you observe that extra "," in between two objects:

```
'80' },
      ,
      { connectionName:
```

Comment: Don't use delete to remove array items; use splice. When you use delete that leaves a "hole" in the array, so the extra comma when you log is indicating the missing element at index 1.

Comment: only use delete to remove object properties

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove array item use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead of `delete`

```
a.splice(1, 1);
```

And just to be clear. `splice` will mutate the original array.

Comment: I would suggest `slice` over `splice`, or even `filter`

Comment: @azium OP wants to change the original array.

Comment: @azium - why? If you know you want to remove exactly one item at index x, filter is an overly complicated way to go about it.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't know about overkill.. the syntax is short, it reads well and it doesn't mutate. `a.filter(x => x.connectionName !== "conn1")`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I doubt that's an OP requirement. Slicing to a new array would almost surely end up with the same requirement being fulfilled.

Comment: @azium - What's wrong with mutating the array, given that in plain English the desired operation is "remove one item"? Using filter is not as short as splice, and it doesn't read well compared to splice: if you see "splice(1,1)" you can tell instantly what it is doing, whereas with filter you have to stop and think about what the callback is actually doing. Using filter would make more sense if you don't know the index of the item to be deleted. Regarding slice, removing an item in the middle with slice involves two slices plus having to combine the two resulting arrays - way too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.splice(<index>, <numElements>, <newElements>)` to replace a element in the array.

```
var jsonString = '[{"connectionName" : "conn1", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.1","port" : "80"}, {"connectionName" : "conn2", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"}]';
var obj = {"connectionName" : "conn3", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"};

var a  = JSON.parse(jsonString); 
a.splice(1, 1, obj);   // remove starting at index 1, 1 element, and insert obj



console.dir(a);
```

Notice how the original array `a` is modified without having to create a new variable.  I used to use `pop` and `push` but found that `splice` is cleaner when you have multiple elements to insert/remove from the array.

```
var jsonString = '[{"connectionName" : "conn1", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.1","port" : "80"}, {"connectionName" : "conn2", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"}]';
var obj1 = {"connectionName" : "conn3", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"};
var obj2 = {"connectionName" : "conn4", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"};
var obj3 = {"connectionName" : "conn5", "ipaddress" : "127.0.0.100","port" : "760"};

var a  = JSON.parse(jsonString); 
a.splice(1, 1, obj1, obj2, obj3);   // remove starting at index 1, 1 element, and insert obj1, obj2, obj3



console.dir(a);
```